# Coefficient of Friction, Passive Magnetic Bearing

Tags: bearings, electromagnetism

While comparing magnetic bearings to others ceramic bearings, a rough first point maybe to compare would be the two different bearings' coefficients of friction. This is just a thumbnail comparison apart from load bearing, and rpm, and any other metric that one might have with the application in concern. Is there a rough estimate for passive magnetic bearings, for an example to compare with a ceramic bearing might have 0.2, steel bearing 0.8, or this bearing called an Autonomous Decentralized Bearing" : 0.0027, any numbers for a passive magnetic bearing, or for reference any numbers for a similar active magnetic bearing?

Comment: My understanding of magnetic bearings was that they entirely removed contact between components, making the coefficient of friction essentially zero. Do you have a specific application in mind where this is a requirement?

Comment: Its a flywheel type requriement, only in a high vibration environment, industrial, shock is constant, similar to automotive. Comparison, for physical aspects, shock profile is similar to automotive type application(KERS).